# Access Not Configured. +1 API

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-developers-console

I'm trying to get shares counts from Google+ using the Google+ API and catch only error:

> Access Not Configured. +1 API has not been used in project 383866521277 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/pos.googleapis.com/overview?project=383866521277 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

After that I visit recommended link and catch pos.googleapis.com not found. How to enable this API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to access Google APIs you need to register your application on [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=daimto-tutorials-101&duration=P30D).   You have probably already created your credentials.  The API key or Oauth2 credentials you created identifies the application to Google.  The project that was used to create the API key or Oauth2 credentials you are using must have the Google+ API enabled.

Enable API:

What you have forgotten to do is to tell Google which APis you will be accessing.  On the Left hand side look for "Library"  find the Google+ api and enable it.

Error pos.googleapis.com

[image]

Means that you do not have access to the project 383866521277 or it was deleted.  The person who created the project must enable the Google+ api for you.  Remember this is denoted by the The API key or Oauth2 credentials you created and are using in your code.

Comment: I have enabled Google+ api

Comment: It should begin to work as soon as you enable it.   Remember if you are using any other APIs to also enable them.

Comment: Probably not on the correct project because you are getting pos.googleapis.com it means you don't have access to the project you are running with.    You must enable it on the project you created which you are using the credentials for.